# Azure download_blob in Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to download and read from a blob with Python.
The blob content looks like lines, where each line is a string representing a json. Something like this:

```
{"time":..., "name":..., "last_key":"last_value"}
{"time":..., "name":..., "last_key_2":"last_value_2"}
```

It's a long file filled with lines like these.
Each line actually ends with \r\n

In some point in the code, I'm finiding a specific location of one of the "\n" characters, and then I want to read the line starting from that point. I call the variable indicating the position of this "\n" as start.

I then try to download the blob using offset, this is the complete code I'm trying to run (I'm reading the file in chunks):

```
        start = 0
        while start < (blob_size - 1):
            blob_downloader = client.download_blob(
                    account_url=account_url, container_name=container_name, blob_name=blob_name, offset=start, length=length
                )
            for chunk in blob_downloader.chunks():
                decoded = chunk.decode("utf-8")
                end_line_character_index = decoded.rfind("\n")
                start += end_line_character_index
                # Chunk until the \n without the character \n
                chunk_without_end_line = decoded[0:end_line_character_index]
                for line in chunk_without_end_line.splitlines():
                    line_parsed = json.loads(line)
```

(length is constant in my code).

The problem is, when I read it, the second time "blob_download" is called, I see the line I'm reading as starting like this:

```
"}\r\n {"time":...}
```

I don't understand why, I want it to only start with the {time..." part.
My guess is that I'm not using the offset parameter properly.I'm passing it the character position. I know it's suppose to indicate starting location in bytes. Maybe it's wrong to refer to each character in the file as a single byte?

Does anyone know of this issue and has an idea what can I do?

Comment: there's not enough information here to answer this question. How are you calculating the start position (show code)? How are you then reading the downloaded file (show code)? For this particular question these are very important. You also mention "*In some point in the code*" → show this code...

Comment: @EdoAkse I added the complete code now, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get value from specific start position refer the code below:-

**main.py:-**

```py
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

connection_string = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=valleystrg129;AccountKey=xxxxkzDF+xxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
container_name = "testhubname-applease"
blob_name = "success.txt"
start = 30
length = 100

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container_name, blob_name)

byte_position = blob_client.download_blob(offset=0, length=start).readall().rfind(b"\r\n") + 2
blob_content = blob_client.download_blob(offset=byte_position, length=length).readall().decode('utf-8')

print(blob_content)
```

**Output:-**

[image]